# Can I force `NSum` to sum exactly for many terms?

Tags: numerics, summation

Is there a way to have `NSum` perform an exact term-by-term summation, when the number of terms is finite?

I have a complicated infinite sum in which each term involves a complicated numerical integral. From playing around with things, I can tell that the result stabilizes after 1,000 terms or so. But I am getting different results when running `NSum` without the "Method" option, vs. when I try "EulerMaclaurin" and "WynnEpsilon."

There is another equivalent expression I have tried evaluating, which should give the same result but doesn't involve a sum, and again I'm getting something similar but not close enough. My answers are ranging from 14,000 to 17,000 depending on the method.

Hence I'd like to try summing term-by-term since that should be more accurate.

Comment: Probably `Total` + `Table`: `NSum[..., {i,0,nn}]` -> `Total@Table[...,{i,0,nn}]` ?

Comment: It seems you're looking for the `NSumTerms` option, but consider @Alx's recommendation. In summing the results of numerical integration, possibly the range of answers is due to round-off error -- impossible to say without code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Just use `Sum` instead of `NSum`.

Comment: `Total` was originally designed with these kind of `NSum` use cases in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `N[Sum[...]]` instead of `NSum`, as suggested in Roman's comment, and it worked like a charm.